# Change default Console I/O functions handle

Tags: windows, winapi, console, handle

Is it possible to somehow change standart I/O functions handle on Windows? Language preffered is C++. If I understand it right, by selecting console project, compiler just pre-allocate console for you, and operates all standart I/O functions to work with its handle. So, what I want to do is to let one Console app actually write into another app Console buffer. I though that I could get first´s Console handle, than pass it to second app by a file (I don´t know much about interprocess comunication, and this seems easy) and than somehow use for example prinf with the first app handle. Can this be done? I know how to get console handle, but I have no idea how to redirect printf to that handle. Its just study-purpose project to more understand of OS work behind this. I am interested in how printf knows what Console it is assiciated with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct you can find the source code of application which you want to write in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx. This example show how to write in `stdin` of another application and read it's `stdout`.

For general understanding. Compiler don't "pre-allocate console for you". Compiler use standard C/C++ libraries which write in the output. So if you use for example `printf()` the following code will be executed at the end will look like:

```
void Output (PCWSTR pszwText, UINT uTextLenght) // uTextLenght is Lenght in charakters
{
    DWORD n;
    UINT uCodePage = GetOEMCP();    // CP_OEMCP, CP_THREAD_ACP, CP_ACP
    PSTR pszText = _alloca (uTextLenght);

    // in the console are typically not used UNICODE, so
    if (WideCharToMultiByte (uCodePage,  0, pszwText, uTextLenght,
                             pszText, uTextLenght, NULL, NULL) != (int)uTextLenght)
        return;

    WriteFile (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), pszText, uTextLenght, &n, NULL);
    //_tprintf (TEXT("%.*ls"), uTextLenght, pszText);
    //_puttchar();
    //fwrite (pszText, sizeof(TCHAR), uTextLenght, stdout);
    //_write (
}
```

So if one changes the value of `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` all output will be go to a file/pipe and so on. If instead of `WriteFile` the program use `WriteConsole` function such redirection will not works, but standard C/C++ library don't do this.

If you want redirect of `stdout` not from the child process but from the current process you can call `SetStdHandle()` directly (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686244%28VS.85%29.aspx).

The "allocating of console" do a loader of operation system. It looks the word of binary EXE file (in the Subsystem part of `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680339%28VS.85%29.aspx) and if the EXE has 3 on this place (`IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_CUI`), than it use console of the parent process or create a new one. One can change a little this behavior in parameters of `CreateProcess` call (but only if you start child process in your code). This `Subsystem` flag of the EXE you define with respect of linker switch /subsystem (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you want the Windows API function `AttachConsole(pid)`, which attaches the current process to the console owned by the process whose PID is `pid`.

Comment: I think you're right. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681952%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect `printf` to a handle (FILE*), just do

```
fprintf(handle, "...");
```

For example replicating `printf` with `fprintf`

```
fprintf(stdout, "...");
```

Or error reporting

```
fprintf(stderr, "FATAL: %s fails", "smurf");
```

This is also how you write to files. `fprintf(file, "Blah.");`

Comment: Thanks. So, fprintf is redirectable printf? And, how does printf know which console is it´s default?

Comment: printf by default goes to whatever "stdout" is refering to, the standart output. Mostly the console, or if you redirect ("yourprogram >output.txt") the redirected file.